# org-agenda not showing any todos

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

No items are showing when I load the agenda view. When I press `C-c a`, the agenda view menu comes up fine. But hitting `a` brings up an empty list, and so does `t`.

`M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-files` shows

[image]

There are tonnes of TODO items in `~/org/todo.org`, eg:

[image]

My init is defined in `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and I do not have an `~/.emacs`. My `init.el` has only one definition of `org-agenda-files`.

I really am at a loss as to why this is not working.

Emacs version 26.3
Org version 9.3.1

Not sure what other information might be useful?

I have been using Emacs for a while, but would consider myself a noob with custom configuration and org mode.

**UPDATE**:

The Messages buffer is showing errors like this:

```
Press key for agenda command (unrestricted):
org-agenda-get-todos: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, "E"
user-error: Command not allowed in this line [3 times]
```

I set `debug-on-entry` for `org-agenda-get-todos`, and it shows this in the debug buffer:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* org-agenda-get-todos()
org-agenda-get-day-entries("~/org/todo.org" (1 21 2020) :todo)
org-todo-list(nil)
funcall-interactively(org-todo-list nil)
call-interactively(org-todo-list)
org-agenda(nil)
funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
command-execute(org-agenda)
```

Comment: Do any of your TODO items have dates?

Comment: Yes, I have some with deadlines (eg. `DEADLINE: <2020-01-22 Wed>`

Comment: OTOH, `t` should show all TODO items whether they have dates or not, so there's probably more to the story.

Comment: Yup, that's why I've been trying both `a` and `t`.

Comment: Can you post your settings? Maybe do `M-x org-submit-bug-report` but don't send it: just cut and paste your settings into the question.

Comment: Try that I get an error: `Symbol's function definition is void: org-dynamic-block-define`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103540/discussion-between-nickd-and-stevenmurray).

Comment: Do you have more than one version of org-mode installed, perhaps some portion of an old version lurking somewhere? Often this is a common source of org issues.

Comment: I do not believe so: I've checked `M-x org-version` and it gives me `Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/org/)`

Comment: Have you done this `Ctr+c [` This will add your org file to the agenda file

Answer (score 1):

The solution here was that I had the following lines in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(setq org-highest-priority "A")
(setq org-lowest-priority "E")
(setq org-default-priority "B")
```

But they should have been

```
(setq org-highest-priority ?A)
(setq org-lowest-priority ?E)
(setq org-default-priority ?B)
```

Comment: I should have suggested that you toggle debug-on-error. That would have given you a stack trace that might have avoided much of the pain you went through. You might want to try it out in any case: reintroduce the bug, say `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and try again. This is a useful technique that you should probably have in your emacs toolbox.
The other useful technique is to start emacs with the -q option, which avoids loading your init file. If the error is caused by your settings, then this will avoid them. You can then bisect your way through your init file to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!